# Why doesn't margin-left work?

Tags: html, css, margin

I want to position my text using CSS, but `margin-left` doesn't do that, unless I put something huge like `margin-left:600px;`.

Why does this happen?

**HTML**

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>WK500 K1</p>
                <img src="WK500 K1/kulg.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <p class="wk540">WK540 K1</p>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="WK540 K1/kulg.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wk540{
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: It does work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vLvo3ood/. You probably have some conflicting CSS. Please show more code.

Comment: Yea, somewhy that code works on jsfiddle, but not in server

Comment: Works fine here.Need the complete code, something must be overriding it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3238r5t7/   it doesnt work when its in a desktop mode, but work fine in a mobile mode

Comment: Why dont you put `<p class="wk540">WK540 K1</p>` inside `<div class="col-md-6">`?

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/3238r5t7/2/

Comment: Well, that did the job, quite a silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: if you want an answer to your original question it is because the col-md-6 are floated left (if you are using some sort of bootstrap) and your paragraph is not, if you floated that left too then your margin would work as expected

Answer (score 0):

The `paragraph tag` is weak... So try putting it in a `<div>` and place the margin on the `<div>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Instead of margin-left, use text-align: left.

```
.wk540 {
    margin-left: 50px;
    text-align: left;
}
```